# Anyone can include in PCRE2 the JIT function?

Tags: c

I wrote a working pcre2.c. Now i want to modify it to work with JIT compile and jit match, but i don't get it working with the FAQ of pcre2 page.

http://www.rtsdd.ru/downloads/ADANCURSESN/pcre2-10.31/src/pcre2_jit_match.c

```
re = pcre2_compile(
  pattern,               /* the pattern */
  PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, /* indicates pattern is zero-terminated */
  PCRE2_CASELESS,        /* default options */
  &errornumber,          /* for error number */
  &erroroffset,          /* for error offset */
  NULL);                 /* use default compile context */

if (re == NULL)
  {
  PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
  pcre2_get_error_message(errornumber, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  printf("PCRE2 compilation failed at offset %d: %s\n", (int)erroroffset,
    buffer);
  return 1;
  }


match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re, NULL);

rc = pcre2_match(
  re,                   /* the compiled pattern */
  subject,              /* the subject string */
  subject_length,       /* the length of the subject */
  55,                   /* start at offset 0 in the subject */
  0,                    /* default options */
  match_data,           /* block for storing the result */
  NULL);                /* use default match context */

}
```

The JIT part has to include after the pcre2_compile().
But i havn't found a working solution.

Comment: The actual [official documentation](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2jit.html) has an example program that shows how to use jit compilation. It works quite well in my uses of the feature.

Comment: I found on web JPCRE2, there i got the JIT COMPILE working but it's cpp. Would be nice when a c expert can present a solution here. The official documentation isn't really a help for me, i get the compile of re working. But no result with JIT.